# How can i get SharePoint list data in ASP.NET page

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2013

I am creating  a site that is accessible from outer domain user is authenticate from SharePoint AD and than i need to display SharePoint site data on that list.My SharePoint is accessible only within internal domain. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please mention what have you tried, and what has worked/not worked and maybe we could help from there.

Comment: I want to use SharePoint rest API. I facing problem in format of ajax request that return access token when i pass my window credential and than i can use that access token for all my ajax request to getting data from SharePoint List.

Comment: if cross domain, you can use/build some proxy service in SharePoint site, then call it from different domain, or you can use sharepoint CSOM dll.
If it's 2013 or Office 365 then you can use cross domain library:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx